# Grunt notification on done [using event?]

Tags: javascript, node.js, notifications, gruntjs

In Grunt, I have a long build process, which requires the user to check the console every time for the `Done, without errors.` message in order for them to know when the build process is done.

I am trying to implement a proper notification for the grunt build to be able to let the user know when the process is over.

I have tried using [grunt-notify](https://github.com/dylang/grunt-notify) with:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-notify');`
```

..in order to get the build process to notify, but this notifies of the process, and not of it ending.

Is there a proper method of programmatically notifying on process end?

Please note the process does not have a deterministic end point, as it is used for several different flows, so I cannot add a line at the end of the last task. I'd like to be able to catch a done event of a kind, or something along this idea.

Bonus points: notifying of errors as well would be nice but not necessary.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `grunt-notify` should notify of success if you use the `success: true` option